# HQL Query fails when using join and with clause

Tags: grails, hql, grails-orm

Good Evening,

I am using Grails and I am trying to do an HQL Query

I have an object Opportunity and inside it an object Entity and inside the Entity a collection of Titles. Each Title object can be main or not (main is a boolean field that shows which of the titles is the default one). So the query that I am doing is this:

select opportunity from Opportunity as opportunity join opportunity.entity.titles as entityTitle with entityTitle.isMain is true

But this query fails with this message:

org.hibernate.hql.ast.InvalidWithClauseException: with-clause expressions did not reference from-clause element to which the with-clause was associated.

I have tried adding the Entity and Title tables and still it fails. If I remove the with clause it works correctly but I need to filter the titles.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. First I had to join the entity to the *Opportunity* and then join the titles to the *Opportunity*. So the query is like this:

```
select opportunity from Opportunity as opportunity 
join opportunity.entity activeEntity 
  with activeEntity.isActive is true 
join activeEntity.titles entityTitle 
  with entityTitle.isActive is true
```

Comment: Exactly. Just added a version with inner join and you would also need to use `distinct`. Also note, `isActive` was not mentioned in the question so I havn't taken that into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select distinct op from Opportunity as op 
inner join op.entity as ent 
inner join ent.titles as tit 
with tit.isMain is true
```